# Why mysqli_escape_string() adds backslash in database ? (PHP 7.4)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to put strings containing single and double quotes in my database but when I use mysqli_escape_string() on it before, it adds backslashes. If I am not mistaken, normally once in the database there should no longer be backslashes ?

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if($conn->connect_error) die('Database error : '.$conn->connect_error);

$strValue = mysqli_escape_string($conn,"a'b");

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (strValue) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $strValue);
$stmt->execute();

// a'b becomes a\'b in database
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using escape string though

Comment: But in this case there is a risk of injection ? the string comes from a user input

Comment: no there is as far as we know no chance for a sql injection with prepared statements

Comment: Okeeey so if I understood correctly, we use mysqli_escape_string()  when we don't use prepared statements to be able to "secure" the value ? And this is not necessary when using prepared statements ?

Comment: That is correct @Miscell and that is the reason why the slashes are included when saved. Go with the prepared statements method instead. PDO also offers a prepared statement.

Comment: You should never ever use `mysqli_escape_string()`. Just stick to using placeholders and parameter binding.

Comment: Okay thank you everyone ! I could have stayed trying to fix the problem for a long time ..